# How to use callback in comment on telegram bot use php

Tags: php

```
$reply  = $name . "\n" . $price . " افغانی " . "\n\n";

$reply .= "/booking"   . $id . "    " . "خرید" . "\n" ;
$reply .= "/delete" . $id . "    " . "حذف"    . "\n\n";

$url = $GLOBALS['bot_url'] . "/sendPhoto";
$post_params = [
    'chat_id' => $GLOBALS['chat_id'],
    'photo'   => new CURLFile(realpath($image_url)),
    'caption' => $reply
];
send_reply($url, $post_params);
}

$connection->close();

//---------------------

$inline_keyboard = [
    [
        ['text' => "ثبت محصول جدید", 'callback_data' => "add_new_product"]
    ]
];

$inline_kb_options = [
    'inline_keyboard' => $inline_keyboard
];

$json_kb = json_encode($inline_kb_options);
$reply   = "جهت افزودن محصول جدید دکمه زیر را لمس کنید";
$url = $GLOBALS['bot_url'] . "/sendMessage";
$post_params = ['chat_id' => $GLOBALS['chat_id'], 'text' => $reply, 'reply_markup' => $json_kb];
send_reply($url, $post_params);
```

}

I want to use `'callback_data' => "add_new_product"` in here  `$reply .= "/booking"   . $id . "    " . "خرید" . "\n";`

How to use it? please help me